# How to find DNS Server IP address of Mac machine?

Tags: cocoa, ip-address

I can find IP address of my Mac machine using:

```
[[[NSHost currentHost] addresses] objectAtIndex:0]
```

But I also want DNS Server IP address of my Mac machine. Any idea how can I get DNS Server IP address of my Mac machine with my Cocoa application??

Comment: What do you want to do? Please explain your needs a little more precise.
Why do you need to get the DNS server in your application????

Comment: @QwertyBob 1) I accepted answers which are useful for me. You can see my questions for that. 2) My system is connected to a network via LAN card. And each system in our network is provided with one IP address of the system and one DNS Server IP for the server and DNS Server IP is different than IP address of the system. I can see this in System Preferences>Network>Ethernet.

Comment: @LivingSkull I'm using concept of LAN syncing in my application. So for that purpose I want IP address of the server so that I can determine if two or more systems are from same network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amrinder,

I think I have found a link that could help you to solve the problem. Check [Apple's System Configuration Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_Intro/SC_Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001065-CH201-TPXREF101)

You should be able to retrieve the needed information from there, for you local MAC.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by running command "netstat -rn" and read output of this command. And find default gateway from output of this command.